# .htaccess error , loop redirection on https transfer

Tags: php, .htaccess

My current .htaccess

> > ## Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php RewriteEngine on Options -Indexes
>
> ```
> > # $Id: .htaccess 1739 2007-12-20 00:52:16Z hpdl $
> > #
> > # This is used with Apache WebServers
> > #
> > # For this to work, you must include the parameter 'Options' to
> > # the AllowOverride configuration
> > #
> > # Example:
> > #
> > # <Directory "/usr/local/apache/htdocs">
> > #   AllowOverride Options
> > # </Directory>
> > #
> > # 'All' with also work. (This configuration is in the
> > # apache/conf/httpd.conf file)
> > # The following makes adjustments to the SSL protocol for Internet
> > # Explorer browsers
> > # <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>    #      <IfDefine SSL>
> >       #    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
> >       #             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
> >       #             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
> >       #      </IfDefine>    # </IfModule>
> > # If Search Engine Friendly URLs do not work, try enabling the
> > # following Apache configuration parameter
> > # AcceptPathInfo On
> > # Fix certain PHP values
> > # (commented out by default to prevent errors occuring on certain
> > # servers)
> > # php_value session.use_trans_sid 0
> > # php_value register_globals 1
> > # For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
> > #Options +FollowSymLinks Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch RewriteBase / RewriteRule ^(.*)-p-(.*).html$
> > product_info.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} RewriteRule
> > ^(.*)-c-(.*).html$ index.php?cPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} RewriteRule
> > ^(.*)-m-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?manufacturers_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
> > RewriteRule ^(.*)-pi-([0-9]+).html$
> > popup_image.php?pID=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} RewriteRule
> > ^(.*)-t-([0-9]+).html$ articles.php?tPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
> > RewriteRule ^(.*)-a-([0-9]+).html$
> > article_info.php?articles_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} RewriteRule
> > ^(.*)-pr-([0-9]+).html$
> > product_reviews.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} RewriteRule
> > ^(.*)-pri-([0-9]+).html$
> > product_reviews_info.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} RewriteRule
> > ^(.*)-i-([0-9]+).html$ information.php?info_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
> > # File modified on Tue Apr 12 09:18:52 2011 by server
> > # For security reasons, mod_php is not used on this server. Use a php.ini file for php directives
> > # php_value auto_append_file /home2/syntecon/public_html/Thumbs.db AuthName "Public_Html"
> ```
>
> AuthUserFile
>
> > "/home2/syntecon/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"

When i am trying to add https redirect : using

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

or

```
rewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
rewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Or any further method , I am keep getting.

> redirected you too many times.

Needs help you redirect everypage of the website.

Thanks

Comment: If that above really is your dynamic configuration file then you are using an invalid file and should get entries in your http servers error log file about that. What does that file say?

Comment: Error Log : https://anotepad.com/notes/w2qrpg

Comment: If that really is your http servers error log file then you certainly have disabled error logging or logging in general.

Comment: I got this logs from /public_html

Comment: Where they certainly do not belong, assuming that this is the folder published via the http server. Look at it yourself: the last entry is over a year old. No restart of the http server since? No script kiddie trying to find vulnerabilities? No accidentally entered misspelled URL? Not a single error anywhere?